# Como programar um botão no unity que após ser clicado, mostre um texto com informações na tela?

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Eu não gostaria de ter que criar outra Cena de novo para mostrar a informação... Gostaria de mostrar na mesma tela ela e sem deixar embolado.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você deseja exibir um pop-up? Ou apenas uma caixa com o texto dentro do jogo?

Comment: então, Eu gostaria que fosse assim. Eu tenho um botão "turma de 2009" e quero que ele mostre uma tela com as informações sobre essa turma (basicamente vai ser só os nomes e os números na chamada). Sobre ser pop-up ou caixa de texto dentro do jogo, depende, o que for mais fácil de tirar logo dps de aparecer seria melhor(pq o usuário pode querer voltar para a tela anterior dps de ver a lista) .

Answer (score 1):

Segue um pequeno script em C# para criar um objeto que é uma caixa de mensagem:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MessageBox : MonoBehaviour
{
     //A janela 200x300 px aparecerá no centro da tela.
     private Rect windowRect = new Rect ((Screen.width - 200)/2, (Screen.height - 300)/2, 200, 300);
     //Variavel para controlar a visibilidade.
     private bool show = false;

    void OnGUI () 
    {
        if(show)
            windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, DialogWindow, "Turma de 2009");
    }

    //Este é o metodo que cria a janela
    void DialogWindow (int windowID)
    {
        float y = 20;

        //Insere um label com o texto desejado
        GUI.Label(new Rect(5,y, windowRect.width, 20), "Texto desejado");

        //Texto para fechar a janela
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(5,y, windowRect.width - 10, 20), "Fechar"))                 
           show = false;        
    }

    //Para abrir o diálogo de você chama este método no botão que você criou na tela
    public void Open()
    {
        show = true;
    }
}
```

Não consegui realizar os testes aqui por que estou sem a Unity instalada